# Global variable doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the dimensions of a image without to have it in DOM.

```
var myVariable;
$('<img src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg"/>').load(function(){
    myVariable = this.width;
}); 
console.log(myVariable);
```

Why console show that myVarible is undefined ?

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/8Tu7j/). It may help you understand the order of execution.

Comment: So "loaded img" show up first. What should I do, then ?

Comment: Put your code in the `load` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image loading happens in separate requests.

`myVariable` will be set to the width at an arbitrary time in the future, almost always after that `console.log` call happens.

Comment: So ... what should I do ?

Comment: @George02 Do whatever it is you need to do in the callback? I mean, you can't get the width until you have the image, unless you can calculate/retrieve the length in some other way.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is undefined, because it's initialized after image is loading, or in another words: `console.log` calls early then function in `load`.